# Show that $\sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 58 n^2} = - \frac{\pi \ln( 27 + 5 \sqrt {29})}{\sqrt {58}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-number-theory, zeta-functions

I wonder why this is true

$$ \sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 58 n^2} = - \frac{\pi \ln( 27 + 5 \sqrt {29})}{\sqrt {58}} $$

Where the sum omits the case $n = m = 0$ ofcourse.

Comment: Not sure If related but is N(sqrt(58)) a ufd ? I think so.

Comment: For sure, $h(-232)=2$ (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) hence there are just two binary reduced quadratic forms of discriminant $-232$, namely $m^2+58n^2$ and $2m^2+29n^2$, so the problem boils down to computing the value of a Dirichlet L-function.

Comment: Im not into Class Numbers , L-functions etc :( A pure calculus explaination ?? Btw where does - 232 come from ??

Comment: The discriminant of $a^2+58b^2$ is $-4\cdot 58=-232$. Similar results do not hold if $58$ is replaced by a random integer, such series encode the arithmetic structure of certain quadratic fields in a very strict way.

Comment: I only know the discriminant for univariate polynomials ...

Comment: But a homogeneous quadratic polynomial is not that different. The discriminant of $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$ is defined as $B^2-4AC$ as expected. Would you mind mentioning *why* you are digging into the theory of integer quadratic forms (and beyond) and your actual attempts?

Comment: I was Just amazed and inspired.

Comment: @mick:  MathJax hint:  to get multicharacter things under the square root sign, put them in braces.  For example, \sqrt{58} gives $\sqrt {58}$ compared with \sqrt 58 which gives $\sqrt 58$.  The Chaz fixed the body but not the title.  It works everywhere-exponents, subscripts, fractions, etc.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The integer $10$ works as well. The family $d=5,\,13,\,37$ probably involves a cross term. Kindly see comment/answer below.

Comment: It is an irony that Ramanujan never went after these sums even after being an expert in elliptic function theory. Had he been there algebraic number theory would not have been so unnecessarily difficult topic to handle. The sum can be evaluated easily via [Kronecker second limit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_limit_formula).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Can you edit my answer and add the closed-forms for $$\sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{2m^2 + p\,n^2}=\;\color{red}?$$ for $p=3,5,11,29$? Thanks.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: I have not evaluated them in closed form. Perhaps it will require some laborious calculations related to eta functions.

Comment: Using Kronecker limit formula (see previous comment) we get the general formula $$\sum_{m, n\in \mathbb {Z}}'\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^{2}+pn^{2}}=-\frac{\pi\log(2g_{p} ^{4})}{\sqrt{p}}$$ where $p>0$ and $g_{p} $ denotes one of Ramanujan's class invariants. If $p$ is rational then $g_{p} $ is algebraic.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: there is a closed form available for many values of $p$ as my last comment suggests. Although I must say getting the algebraic number $g_{p} $ in explicit form for any arbitrary positive rational $p$ is difficult.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I added an update to express the Ramanujan class invariant $g_p$ into a more familiar eta quotient.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Please try to give all the clues you know in your answers (see mine, I took 1 hour to write it)

Comment: @reuns: the formula I gave in my comment has been used by Tito to give the evaluations of the sums. If one accepts the Kronecker (second) limit formula, then one immediately gets the answer in terms of Ramanujan's class invariants. Kronecker limit formula does not appear to have an easy and accessible proof (at least my online searches have been totally ineffective in finding easy proofs of any result with Kronecker's name in it, say Kronecker Weber Theorem).

Comment: @reuns : Ramanujan defines two functions of a real variable $q$ via infinite products $$G(q) =2^{-1/4}q^{-1/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+q^{2n-1}),g(q)=2^{-1/4}q^{-1/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n-1}) $$ and proved that these functions take algebraic values if $q=\exp(-\pi\sqrt{p}) $ if $p$ is a positive rational. The corresponding values of the function are denoted by $G_{p}, g_{p} $ and called class invariant (the term is borrowed from Weber). He also gave a method to evaluate these algebraic numbers and worked out details for small values of $p$.

Comment: @reuns : Ramanujan was not so much of an abstract theorist. When he said that a certain quantity can be evaluated in closed form, he meant that he had performed the calculations and had a general procedure to do these evaluations. So much better than the modular form guys / cft guys who are trying to guess algebraic numbers based on the degree of polynomials satisfied by them.

Comment: @reuns : you may have a look at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/ramanujans-class-invariants.html where some class invariants have been evaluated in a manner specified by Ramanujan.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It doesn't seem very different to evaluating $j(a+b\sqrt{-d})$, which is the same as finding the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ or finding an elliptic curve with complex multiplication by $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$. In general, once we know $j(a+b\sqrt{-d})$ and if $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d},j(a+b\sqrt{-d}))/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian then we can evaluate $\sum_{n,m} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+d m^2}$ in term of Dirichlet L-functions as in my answer.

Comment: @reuns : that's what Weber did. Unfortunately his work is also lost in translation (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/438643/72031) and modern mathematicians tried best to make the work of guys like Kronecker / Weber inaccessible.

Comment: @reuns: Hi reuns. I believe Paramanand addressed your query. The case $p=10$ was inspired guesswork, but I used his closed-form and _Mathematica's_ integer-relations to find $p=6,22$.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I managed to sum this series using [Ramanujan's class invariants](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/ramanujans-class-invariants.html). We have the definition $$g(q) = 2^{-1/4}q^{-1/24}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2n - 1}), \, g_{p} = g(e^{-\pi\sqrt{p}})\tag{1}$$ Ramanujan established that if $p$ is a positive rational number then $g_{p}$ is an algebraic real number. Moreover we have the non-trivial identity $$g_{4/p} = 1/g_{p}\tag{2}$$ Another ingredient we need is the formula $$\sin \pi z = \pi z\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(1 - \frac{z^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)\tag{3}$$ Taking logs and differentiating with respect to $z$ we get $$\pi\cot\pi z = \frac{1}{z} -2z \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2} - z^{2}}$$ Replacing $z$ by $iz$ we get $$\pi\coth\pi z = \frac{1}{z} + 2z\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2} + z^{2}}$$ The above sum can be written as $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2} + z^{2}} = \frac{\pi}{2z} - \frac{1}{2z^{2}} + \frac{\pi e^{-2\pi z}}{z(1 - e^{-2\pi z})}\tag{4}$$ Consider the sum in question
\begin{align}
S(p) &= \sum_{m, n\in\mathbb{Z}}'\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^{2} + pn^{2}}\notag\\
&= 2\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^{2}} + 2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^{2} + pn^{2}}\notag\\
&= 2\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^{2}} + \frac{2}{p}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}+ 4\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^{2} + pn^{2}}\notag\\
&=\frac{(2- p)\pi^{2}}{6p} + 4\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^{2} + pn^{2}}\notag\\
&=\frac{(2- p)\pi^{2}}{6p} + 4\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^{2} + pn^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{(2- p)\pi^{2}}{6p} + \frac{4}{p}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^{2}(1/p) + n^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{(2- p)\pi^{2}}{6p} + \frac{4}{p}\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{p}}{2m} - \frac{p}{2m^{2}} + \frac{\pi\sqrt{p} e^{-2\pi m/\sqrt{p}}}{m(1 - e^{-2\pi m/\sqrt{p}})}\right)\text{ (using equation }(4)) \notag\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{3p}-\frac{2\pi\log 2}{\sqrt{p}}+\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{p}}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m}q^{m}}{m(1-q^{m})},\,q=e^{-2\pi/\sqrt{p}}\notag\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{3p}-\frac{\pi\log 4}{\sqrt{p}}+\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{p}}(a(q^{2})-a(q))\notag\\
&\, \, \, \, \,\,\,\,\text{where }a(q) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n}} {n(1-q^{n})}=-\log\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{n})\notag\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{3p}-\frac{\pi\log 4} {\sqrt{p}}+\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{p}}\log\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n-1}) \notag\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{3p}-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt {p}} \log\frac{2}{q^{1/6}g^{4}(q)}\text{ (via equation }(1)) \notag\\
&= -\frac{\pi\log(2/g_{4/p}^{4})}{\sqrt{p}}\notag\\
&= -\frac{\pi\log (2g_{p}^{4})}{\sqrt{p}}\text{ (using equation }(2))\notag
\end{align}
It is well known that $g_{58} = \sqrt{(5 + \sqrt{29})/2}$ and this gives the desired closed form for $S(58)$. The above technique can also be used ([with some more effort](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2483738/72031)) to prove the Kronecker's second limit formula.

---

The function $a(q) $ used above is related to work of Simon Plouffe. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938644/72031) for details.

Comment: nice answer (+1)...i was fiddeling around with dedekind etas but gave up. they seem to be quiet closely related to the class invariants you are using..

Comment: @tired: oh yes the class invariants can be expressed in terms of eta functions. For the current case just note that $\prod(1-q^{2n-1})=\prod(1-q^{n})/(1-q^{2n})$ so that it is essentially $\eta(q) /\eta(q^{2}) $.

Answer (score 5):

- Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-58}),\mathcal{O}_F=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-58}]$.
  Its ideal class group is $C_F= \{ (1),(2,\sqrt{-58})\}$

  thus the ideals with their norm are $N((n+\sqrt{-58}m))= n^2+58m^2$, $  N(\frac{2n+\sqrt{-58}m}{2}(2,\sqrt{-58}))= \frac12(4n^2+58m^2)$

  > then **your series is $\ \ 2 \ L(1,\psi)$**

  where $\psi((n+\sqrt{-58}m))=1, \psi(\frac{2n+\sqrt{-58}m}{2}(2,\sqrt{-58}))=-1$ is the Hecke character induced by the non-trivial character of $C_F$.
  $$  L(s,\psi) = \sum_I \psi(I) N^{-s} =\frac{1}{|\mathcal{O}_F^\times|} \sum_{n,m \in \mathbb{Z}^2}' N((n+\sqrt{-58}m))^{-s}- 2^{s}  N((2n+\sqrt{-58}m))^{-s}$$
- Using $|C_F| = 2$ and some class field theory, we find that $H = F(\sqrt{-2})$ is the Hilbert class field of $F$ and $$\zeta_H(s) = \zeta_F(s) L(s,\psi)$$

  Now by chance it happens that $H/\mathbb{Q}$ is itself an abelian extension. Thus we can write $\zeta_H$ as a product of Dirichlet L-functions

  $$\zeta_H(s) = \zeta(s)\ L(s,{\scriptstyle \left(\frac{-58}{.}\right)})\ L(s,{\scriptstyle \left(\frac{-2}{.}\right)})\ L(s,{\scriptstyle \left(\frac{29}{.}\right)})$$
  Together with $\displaystyle\zeta_F(s) = \zeta(s)\ L(s,{\scriptstyle \left(\frac{-58}{.}\right)})$ it means $$L(1,\psi) = L(1,{\scriptstyle \left(\frac{-2}{.}\right)})\ L(1,{\scriptstyle \left(\frac{29}{.}\right)})$$
  and we use quadratic reciprocity to write $(\frac{-d}{.}) = (\frac{.}{\Delta})$ and conclude.

Comment: Funny to see a rather innocuous looking sum solved using Hecke Characters and Class Field Theory. +1

Answer (score 3):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

We have,

$$ \sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 10n^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln( \sqrt2\; U_{5})}{\sqrt {10}} $$

$$ \sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 58 n^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln( \sqrt2\; U_{29})}{\sqrt {58}} $$

with *[fundamental units](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalUnit.html)* $U_5 = \frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ and $U_{29} = \frac{5+\sqrt{29}}2$.

**P.S.** Presumably there might be a family for $d = 5,\,13,\,37$.

---

***Added:***

Courtesy of [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469841/sum-m-n-infty-infty-frac-1mm2-58-n2-frac-pi-ln-27?noredirect=1#comment5104526_2469841) by Paramanand Singh, we have the closed-form in terms of the *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$ as,

$$\sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + pn^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln(\sqrt2\,g_p^2)}{\sqrt {p}} =- \frac{\pi \ln(2\,g_p^4)}{\sqrt {p}} $$
where,

> $$g_p = 2^{-1/4}\frac{\eta(\tfrac12\sqrt{-p})}{\eta(\sqrt{-p})}$$

In particular,
$$\sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 6n^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln\big(\sqrt2\,(1+\sqrt2)^{1/3}\big)}{\sqrt{6}}$$
$$\sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 22n^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln\big(\sqrt2\,(1+\sqrt2)\big)}{\sqrt{22}}$$
and more complicated ones for $d=5,\,13,\,37$.

Comment: Glad to see your update. When there are too my comments people may not read all of them. Putting that comment as a part of answer (with additional details) will make it more accessible. I had already delivered my +1 so just thanks for now.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I upvoted your comment with the formula so it goes into the top 5.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I believe there should be a similar formula for $$\sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{am^2 +amn+p n^2}$$ especially for $a=1$ and $a=2$.

Comment: I am not sure, perhaps some algebraic number theory expert can help. You may ask it as a separate question. It might be possible to transform $am^{2}+amn+pn^{2} $ into $rM^{2}+sN^{2}$ where $M, N$ are linear combinations of $m, n$ in such a manner that if $m, n$ take all integer values then $M, N$ also take all integer values. This will reduce the problem to current one.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I've asked the question in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478688/what-is-the-closed-form-for-displaystyle-sum-m-n-infty-infty-frac).