# What is the closed-form for $\displaystyle\sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + mn+41n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-number-theory, radicals, zeta-functions

Omitting the case $m = n = 0$, if,

$$ \sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 58 n^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln\big(\tfrac{5 + \sqrt {29}}{\sqrt2}\big)}{\sqrt {58}} $$

as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469841/show-that-sum-m-n-infty-infty-frac-1mm2-58-n2-frac), then is,

$$ \sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + mn+ 41 n^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln\big(\beta\big)}{\sqrt {163}} $$

for some algebraic number $\beta$? *If yes, then what is* $\beta$?

---

**P.S.** Incidentally, we have the nice approximation,

$$e^{\pi\sqrt{58}} \approx \Big(\tfrac{5 + \sqrt {29}}{\sqrt2}\Big)^{12} +23.999999988776\dots$$

and the "excess" near $24$ has to do with the Dedekind eta function.

Comment: @Tito The method is the same as for the previous question. It seems you don't care of the maths, only of the result, I have a problem with that.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Can you convert that as an answer?

Comment: Ok will add an answer with some details.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Preferably with $\beta$'s minimal polynomial. I believe its degree is $3m$, right?

Comment: There was some typo in my comment (now deleted) as well as in my answer (which is now fixed). The thing to note is that $m^{2}+mn+41n^{2}=(m+n\tau)(m+n\overline{\tau})$ if $2\tau=1+i\sqrt{163}$ (earlier version had $2\tau=-1+i\sqrt{163}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is a result which goes by the name of **Kronecker's second limit formula**. Using the formulation given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_limit_formula) it can be proved that the desired sum in question is equal to $$-\frac{2\pi\log|2g^{4}(q)|} {\sqrt{163}} $$ where $q=\exp(\pi i\tau), 2\tau=1+i\sqrt{163}$ and $$g(q) =2^{-1/4}q^{-1/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n-1})$$ With some manipulation it can be shown that the above sum is equal to $$-\frac{\pi\log(2G_{163}^{4})}{\sqrt{163}}$$ The value of $$G_{163}=\frac{6+\sqrt[3]{135-3\sqrt{489}}+\sqrt[3]{135+3\sqrt{489}}} {3\sqrt[4]{2}} $$ is (not so) well known and the calculations explained above can be performed with reasonable amount of labor to obtain a closed form for the sum in question.

Comment: I find that for $2\tau = -1+\sqrt{-163}$, then, $$\beta = \big|2g^4(q)\big| = \left(e^{-\pi i/24}\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}\right)^2=x^2$$ where $x$ is the real root of the rather well-known cubic $x^3-6x^2+4x-2 = 0$. This then yields, $$ \sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + mn+ 41 n^2} = - \frac{2\pi \ln\big(x^2\big)}{\sqrt {163}} = -1.64493406\dots$$ But is the above eta quotient true for general $2\tau = -1+\sqrt{-d}$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: yes I think the relation between eta and Ramanujan $g$ should be valid. And you have finally managed to find the minimal polynomial for $\beta$. Great!

Comment: I've added a supplementary answer to yours below. It seems the two forms can be expressed by $g_n$ and $G_n$ equally simply.

Answer (score 4):

It seems we can get an *aesthetic* summary using Ramanujan's $g_n$ and $G_n$ functions (also via the [Weber modular functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_modular_function)) as,

$$ \sum_{p,q = - \infty}^{\infty}\, \frac{(-1)^p}{p^2 + n q^2} = - \frac{\pi \ln{\big(2\,g^4_n\big)}}{\sqrt {n}} $$

$$ \sum_{p,q = - \infty}^{\infty}\, \frac{(-1)^p}{p^2 + pq+ k q^2} = - \frac{\pi \ln{\big(2\,G^4_n\big)}}{\sqrt {n}} $$

where $n=4k-1$ for $G_n$ and,

$$g_n =2^{-1/4}\,\frac{\eta\big(\tfrac12\sqrt{-n}\big)}{\eta\big(\sqrt{-n}\big)}$$
and,
$$G_n = 2^{-1/4}\,\frac{\eta^2\big(\sqrt{-n}\big)}{\eta\big(\tfrac12\sqrt{-n}\big)\,\eta\big(2\sqrt{-n}\big)}$$

with *Dedekind eta function* $\eta(\tau)$.

---

For example,

$$g_{58} = \sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{29}}2} =2.27872\dots $$
$$G_{163} = 2^{-1/4}x =4.47241\dots$$
with $x$ as the real root of $x^3-6x^2+x-2=0$. Incidentally,

$$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx x^{24}-24.00000000000000105\dots$$

Comment: You should have $n=4k-1$ so that $n>0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Oops, has been corrected.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Do you know of any other situation or MSE post where $g_n$ pops up naturally, but $G_n$ has not been considered to have a role? Or do these two always go together like two sides of the same coin? (Excluding known transformations like $(G_n\,g_n)^8(G^8_n-g^8_n) = \frac14$.)