# Sum the series $\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}} {z+n} +\frac{a^{-n}} {z-n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a=\exp (2\pi i u) $ where $0<u<1$. Then it can be proved using Liouville's theorem that $$f(z, a) =\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a^{n}} {z+n} +\frac{a^{-n}} {z-n}\right)=2\pi i\cdot\frac{a^{-z}} {1-\exp(-2\pi iz)}, z\neq 0$$

> Is there any other way to prove this preferably using some general techniques for summation of a series?

For $a=1$ it is easy to see that $f(z, a) =\pi\cot\pi z$ (based on infinite product of $\sin\pi z$) and I am expecting some similar approach which works for $a\neq 1$.

---

**Note**: For the uninitiated the above identity is crucial to the proof of [Kronecker's second limit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_limit_formula). Apart from this step the formula involves nothing but simple algebraic manipulation and is thus at the same level as the above identity. My interest in Kronecker's formula ignited due to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2469841/72031).

Comment: @reuns: I thought that the series for cotangent was a consequence of infinite product of sine. Let's not worry about this. If there is any other approach, that's fine.

Comment: What proof of $\pi \cot \pi z =\frac1z \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{z+n}+\frac{1}{z-n} $ would you like to extend ? And there is nothing simpler than starting from $2\pi i\frac{a^{-z}} {1-\exp(-2\pi iz)}-\frac{1}{z}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}} {z+n} +\frac{a^{-n}} {z-n}$ is an entire function

Comment: @reuns: entire function approach is the one I have mentioned (Liouville's theorem). But this sort of seems indirect.

Comment: Indirect, or one of the most powerful tool we know in maths (without it we wouldn't know elliptic functions, modular forms, Riemann surfaces, $\zeta(s)$, class field theory..)

Comment: @reuns: i personally like the proof of $1+2+\dots +n=n(n+1)/2$ by reversing the sum as $n+\dots+2+1$ and adding with original. This beats the proof by induction by a wide margin. Modern authors have been so biased by complex analytic techniques that other simpler direct methods have become obsolete. And it has added to a lot of mathematics which has become unnecessarily complicated. The fields which you have mentioned were handled by Ramanujan using much simpler methods to achieve much more than the modern guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This series is one of the simplest cases of a Fourier series:

$\displaystyle e^{-i2\pi uz} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i2\pi uk} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} e^{-i(z+k)t}dt =  \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i2\pi uk} \frac{1-e^{-i2\pi(z+k)}}{i(z+k)} $

$\hspace{1.5cm}\displaystyle =  \frac{1- e^{-i2\pi z} }{i2\pi} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{ e^{i2\pi uk}}{z+k} $

(with which the formula in the question follows)

Comment: Why didn't I manage to think in this manner? :(:(:( Often a simple idea is difficult to come even after much effort. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh : It is not possible to think about everything at any time. Therefore it makes sense to support each other. :-)

Comment: There is a typo in the expression after second $=$. You should have $1-e^{-2\pi i(z+k)} $ in numerator.

Comment: Of course, sorry and thanks!, fixed. :-)

Comment: I wonder if there is any simpler approach available. Will wait for some time before accepting.

Comment: Yes, would be nice to see another (and I hope: very different) approach, which is also not difficult to understand.