Evaluate series of exponential divided by 1st order polynomial (residue theorem?)
While investigating the dynamics of a frequency modulated quantum system I came across this innocently looking series: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu+n} \tag{1},$$ where $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, I tried solving it with the residue theorem assuming that a contour integral enclosing all poles of $$\pi \cot {\pi z} \frac{e^{i z \theta}}{\mu+z} ,\tag{2}$$ equals zero, so then the series in Eq. $(1)$ would equal minus the residue of Eq. $(2)$ at the pole $z=-\mu$, i.e., $$-\pi \cot({-\pi \mu}) e^{-i \mu \theta} \tag{3}.$$
However, when Fourier series expanding this result in Mathematica, it doesn't look quite like the original series. Therefore, I wonder if for example the assumption that the contour integral is zero is wrong (e.g., because of exponential growth being faster than polynomial) and how to calculate it. I'm a physicist and thus my complex analysis skills are quite limited.
Any hints?

See also https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html

A contour integral over a contour $C \subseteq \Omega$ would equal $0$ if the function being integrated is holomorphic in a simply connected domain $\Omega$; more details here. In your case, a contour enclosing finitely many poles of $f(z) = \pi \cot {\pi z} \frac{e^{i z \theta}}{\mu+z}$ would equal the sum of residues of $f$ at those poles, assuming the contour doesn't touch any poles, and enlarging the contour such that everything converges and you recover the infinite series you want. I did similar...

(cont.) examples here and here. Unfortunately, I'm not convinced there's an elementary closed form for that series because WolframAlpha is expressing the series in terms of the  Hurwitz Lerch transcendent here.

See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2483738/72031

Here is another method for performing the sum. We take $\Re (\mu)$ to not be an integer and take $\theta$ to not be equal to $k2 \pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
First we take $0 < \Re (\mu) < 1$. For later convenience, note $\theta= 2 \pi (\frac{\theta}{2 \pi}) = 2 \pi (\lfloor \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \rfloor + \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \})$ where $\lfloor \cdots \rfloor$ is the floor function and $\{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \}$ is the fractional part of $\frac{\theta}{2 \pi}$.
We have
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu + n} 
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\mu} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu + n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-i n \theta}}{-\mu + n}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\mu} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu + n} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} du - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-i n \theta}}{-\mu + n} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\mu} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-u (n+\mu) + in \theta} du - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-u (n -\mu) - in \theta} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\mu} + \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n (u - i \theta)} e^{-u \mu} du - \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n (u+ i\theta)} e^{u \mu} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\mu} + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u \mu}}{e^{u - i \theta} - 1} du - \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{u \mu}}{e^{u + i \theta} - 1} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\mu} + \left[ - \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{e^{-u \mu}}{e^{u - i \theta} - 1} \right]_0^\infty - \frac{1}{\mu} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u \mu} e^{u - i \theta}}{(e^{u - i \theta} - 1)^2} du - \left[ \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{e^{u \mu}}{e^{u + i \theta} - 1} \right]_0^\infty - \frac{1}{\mu} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{u \mu} e^{u + i \theta}}{(e^{u + i \theta} - 1)^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{1}{\mu} + \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{1}{e^{- i \theta} - 1} + \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{1}{e^{i \theta} - 1} - \frac{1}{\mu} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u \mu} e^{u + i \theta}}{(e^u - e^{i \theta})^2} du - \frac{1}{\mu} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{u \mu} e^{u - i \theta}}{(e^u - e^{-i \theta})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = - \frac{1}{\mu} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-u \mu} e^u e^{i \theta}}{(e^u - e^{i \theta})^2} du
\end{align*}
where we have done an integration by parts and the substitution $u \rightarrow - u$ in the second integral in the second to last line (strictly, you need to justify the step where a summation and integration were interchanged). Consider the rectangular contour in the figure

and contour integral:
\begin{align*}
\oint \frac{e^{-z \mu} e^z e^{i \theta}}{(e^z - e^{i \theta})^2} dz
\end{align*}
The whose integrand has pole at $i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \}$. The integral along the vertical edges vanishes as:
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \dfrac{e^{(-\mu+1) (u+iv)} e^{i \theta}}{(e^{u+iv} + e^{i \theta})^2} =
\begin{cases}
     e^{i \theta} e^{(-\mu - 1) (u+iv)} & u \rightarrow \infty \\
     e^{-i \theta} e^{(-\mu+1) (u+iv)}  & u \rightarrow - \infty \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
& e^{i \theta} \oint_C \dfrac{e^{-\mu z}}{(e^z - e^{i \theta})^2}dz
\nonumber \\
& = e^{i \theta} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-\mu u}}{(e^u - e^{i \theta})^2} du - e^{i \theta} e^{- \mu 2 \pi i} \int_{-\infty + 2 \pi i}^{\infty + 2 \pi i} \dfrac{e^{- \mu u}}{(e^u - e^{i \theta})^2} du
\nonumber \\
& = (1-e^{-\mu 2 \pi i}) e^{i \theta} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-\mu u}}{(e^u - e^{i \theta})^2} du
\end{align*}
We arrive a
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{i \theta} e^{-\mu u} e^u}{(e^u - e^{i \theta})^2} du & = \frac{2 \pi i }{1-e^{-\mu 2 \pi i}} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{e^{i \theta} e^{-\mu z} e^z}{(e^z - e^{i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \}})^2} dz
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{2 \pi i}{1-e^{-\mu 2 \pi i}} Res [f(z)]
\end{align*}
We wish to expand the integrand in powers of $z-z_0$ about the pole $z_0= i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \}$. First note:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = \frac{e^{-2 z_0}}{(e^{z-z_0} - 1)^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{e^{-2 z_0}}{[z-z_0 + \frac{1}{2!} (z-z_0)^2 + \cdots]^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{e^{-2 z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2 [1 + \frac{1}{2!} (z-z_0) + \cdots]^2}
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{(z-z_0)^2} - \dfrac{e^{-2z_0}}{z-z_0} + \cdots
\end{align*}
Then note:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{e^{z_0} e^{-\mu z} e^z}{(e^z - e^{z_0})^2} & = e^{-z_0}  \dfrac{ e^{(-\mu + 1) z_0 + (-\mu + 1) (z-z_0)} }{ (z-z_0)^2 } - e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(-\mu + 1) z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(-\mu + 1) z_0} [1 + (-\mu + 1) (z-z_0) + \cdots] }{ (z-z_0)^2 } - e^{-z_0} \dfrac{ e^{(-\mu + 1) z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\nonumber \\
& = \dfrac{ e^{-\mu z_0} }{ (z-z_0)^2 } + \dfrac{ -\mu e^{-\mu z_0} }{ z-z_0 } + \cdots
\end{align*}
Combining everything
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{i \theta} e^{-\mu u}}{(e^u - e^{i \theta})^2} du & = \pi \frac{2i}{1-e^{-\mu 2 \pi i}} \cdot -\mu e^{-\mu i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \}}
\nonumber \\
& = - e^{-\mu i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \} + \mu \pi i} \dfrac{\mu \pi}{\sin \mu \pi}
\end{align*}
Finally, for the case where $0 < \Re (\mu) < 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu + n} = e^{-\mu i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \} + \mu \pi i} \dfrac{\pi}{\sin \mu \pi}
\end{align*}
Now consider the general case where $\mu = m + \{ \mu_R \} + i \mu_I$ with $0 < \{ \mu_R \} < 1$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu + n} & = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\{ \mu_R \} + m + i \mu_I + n}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-i m \theta} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i (n+m) \theta}}{\{ \mu_R \} + i \mu_I + (m+n)}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-i m 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\{ \mu_R \} + i \mu_I + n}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-i m 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \}} e^{-(\{ \mu_R \} + i\mu_I) i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \} + (\{ \mu_R \} + i\mu_I) \pi i} \dfrac{\pi}{\sin (\{ \mu_R \} + i\mu_I) \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = (-1)^m e^{-\mu i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \} + \mu \pi i} \dfrac{\pi}{\sin (\{ \mu_R \} + i\mu_I) \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = e^{-\mu i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \} + \mu \pi i} \dfrac{\pi}{\sin \mu \pi}
\end{align*}
where I have used the trig identity $\sin (-m \pi + \mu \pi) = \cos (-m \pi) \sin \mu \pi = (-1)^m \sin \mu \pi$.
Check: taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$ ($\theta \not=k 2\pi$):
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d \theta} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu + n} = \frac{d}{d \theta} f(\theta) = -i \mu e^{-\mu i 2 \pi \{ \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \} + \mu \pi i} \dfrac{\pi}{\sin \mu \pi} = -i \mu f(\theta)
\end{align*}

The issue is indeed that the contour integral does not vanish.
If $ \theta >0$, then the magnitude of $e^{i z \theta}$ grows exponentially as $\Im(z) \to -\infty$.
And if $\theta <0$, then the magnitude of $e^{iz \theta}$ grows exponentially as $\Im(z) \to + \infty.$
However, we can modify the integrand so that the contour integral does vanish in the case that $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$.
Consider the function $$f(z) = \pi \left(\cot(\pi z) -i \right) \frac{e^{i z \theta}}{\mu + z} = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi z)} \frac{e^{i(\theta - \pi)z}}{\mu +z}, \quad \color{red}{0 < \theta < 2 \pi},$$
and a rectangular contour with vertices at $$z= \pm (N+1/2)\pm i\sqrt{N} ,$$ where $N$ is some large positive integer.
As $N \to \infty$, the integrals along the left and right sides of the contour vanish because  $$ \left| \frac{e^{i(\theta - \pi)(\pm(N+1/2)+it)}}{\sin(\pi (\pm (N+1/2)+it))} \right| = \frac{e^{(\pi - \theta)t}}{\cosh(\pi t)} \le 2 $$ for any $- \sqrt{N} < t < \sqrt{N}$ when $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$.
And the integrals along the top and bottom of the contour vanish as $N \to \infty$ because the magnitude of $$\frac{e^{i(\theta - \pi)z}}{\sin(\pi z)} $$ decays exponentially to zero as $\Im(z) \to \pm \infty$ when $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$.
We therefore have $$ \begin{align} 0 &= 2 \pi i \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname*{Res}_{z= n} f(z) + \operatorname*{Res}_{z = - \mu} f(z)\right) \\ &= 2 \pi i \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu +n} - \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi \mu)} e^{i \mu(\pi - \theta)}\right), \end{align}$$
from which it follows that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{\mu +n} =  \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi \mu)} e^{i \mu(\pi - \theta)}, \quad 0 < \theta < 2 \pi.$$
This agrees with Dave77's generalized result.

This kind of summation is usually represented with the help of Lerch transcendent / Hurwitz zeta function, defined as
$$
\Phi(z,s,a) = \sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}} \frac{z^n}{(n+a)^s}.
$$
It is convergent for $|z| < 1$ or $|z| = 1$ with $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1$ only. In consequence, the quantity
$$
f(\theta) = \sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}} \frac{e^{in\theta}}{n+\mu}
$$
doesn't converge for any $\theta \in \Bbb{R}$, that is why you may consider its analytic continuation on the complex plane instead. What to do next ? Even if the Lerch/Hurwitz function permits to link $f$ to a special function, does the latter admit another (more practical) form ? In fact, it satisfies to a simple differential equation, namely
$$
f'(\theta) = -i\mu f(\theta) + 2\pi i\, \delta(\theta),
$$
where we used the Fourier series representation of the Dirac delta function, i.e.
$$
\delta(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}} e^{in\theta}.
$$
One understands thus that $f$ behaves like the antiderivative of the Dirac delta function, that is the Heaviside function, together with a complex exponential, which is responsible for the translation by $\mu$ in the Fourier series. However, you won't be able to determine a suitable constant of integration on the real line because of the aforementioned divergence issues. Nevertheless, you may use representations of Dirac/Heaviside functions on the complex plane and integrate the differential equation along a curve in the said complex plane.

The sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}}{\mu+n}$ seems to converge for $\mu$ real where $0<\mu<1$ and $x$ real where $x \not= k2\pi$ by Dirichlet's test. For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{\mu + n}$ choose $a_n=1/(\mu+n)$ and $b_n= e^{inx}$. Then $a_1>a_2>\cdots$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$ and $|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{inx}| = |(e^{ix}-e^{i(N+1)x})/(1-e^{ix})| \leq 2/|1-e^{ix}|.$ For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-inx}}{-\mu+n}$ choose $a_n=1/(-\mu+n)$ and $b_n=e^{-in x}$. Then $a_1>a_2>\cdots$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$ and $|\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-inx}| \leq 2/|1-e^{-i x}|.$

Also, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i nx}}{\mu + n}$ converges for $\mu_I \not=0$, $0 \leq \mu_R < 1$ and $x \not= k2\pi$ by Dirichlet. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{i nx}}{\mu_R+i\mu_I + n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\mu_R+n)e^{i nx}}{(\mu_R+n)^2+\mu_I^2}-\mu_I\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{i nx}}{(\mu_R+n)^2+\mu_I^2}$. Consider the 1st sum. Choose $a_n=(\mu_r+n)/((\mu_R+n)^2+\mu_I^2)$ and $b_n=e^{inx}$. To show $a_1<a_2< \cdots$ note $\frac{d}{dy}[(\mu_R+y)/((\mu_R+y)^2+\mu_I^2)]<0$ for $y>0$. The 2nd sum is straightforward. Similarly for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-i nx}}{-\mu_R-i\mu_I + n}$.
