Prove $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e(n \alpha)}{x^2-n^2} = \frac{\pi}{x} \frac{\sin(2 \pi \alpha x) - \sin(2 \pi(\alpha - 1)x)}{1-\cos(2 \pi x)}$

How can I show that, if $0 < x < 1$, then
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e(n \alpha)}{x^2 - n^2} = \frac{\pi}{x} \frac{\sin(2 \pi \alpha x) - \sin(2 \pi (\alpha - 1)x)}{1 - \cos(2 \pi x)},$$
where $e(n \alpha) = e^{2 \pi i n \alpha}$?

This seems to work with Poisson summation given the limits of summation, but I'm not sure how in this particular case. If I haven't done anything wrong, the Fourier transform of $e(t \alpha)/(x^2 - t^2)$ with respect to $t$ should be
$$\frac{1}{x} \sqrt{\pi/2} \operatorname{sgn}(2 \pi \alpha + \omega) \sin(x(2 \pi \alpha + \omega)).$$
Then, we could consider $e^{i x(2 \pi \alpha + \omega)}$, evaluate the corresponding geometric sum, and then take the imaginary part. However, the presence of the $\operatorname{sgn}$ function makes this a little difficult.

See the formula in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2483738/72031 and your sum can be expressed using that formula.

Too long for a comment
The evaluation is basically the same as in this post.
Let's consider
$$S(\alpha, x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha n}}{x^2-n^2}; \,\alpha\in[0;1];\,x\neq0,\pm1,\pm2...$$
To evaluate $S_0$ we integrate the function $\frac{2\pi i}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha z}}{x^2-z^2}$ along the rectangular contour $\,C:\,-N-\frac12-iN\to N+\frac12-iN\to N+\frac12+iN\to-N-\frac12+iN\to-N-\frac12-iN$.
Integral along this contour tends to zero as $N\to \infty$. On the other hand,
$$\oint_C\frac{2\pi i}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha z}}{x^2-z^2}dz=2\pi i\sum \operatorname{Res}\frac{2\pi i}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha z}}{x^2-z^2}$$
The residues at the poles of the function $\frac{2\pi i}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}$ give us $S$; we also have two poles at $z=\pm x$. Hence,
$$S+\underset{z=\pm x}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\,\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha z}}{x^2-z^2}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\,S=\underset{z=\pm x}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha z}}{(z-x)(z+x)}=\frac{2\pi i}{2x}\left(\frac {e^{2\pi i\alpha x-\pi ix}}{e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi ix}}-\frac {e^{-2\pi i\alpha x+\pi ix}}{e^{-\pi ix}-e^{\pi ix}}\right)$$
$$\boxed{\,\,S=\frac\pi x\frac{\cos\big(\pi x(2\alpha-1)\big)}{\sin(\pi x)}\,\,}$$
what is the same as the original form of the answer, because
$$\frac{\sin(2 \pi \alpha x) - \sin(2 \pi (\alpha - 1)x)}{1 - \cos(2 \pi x)}=2\frac{\sin(\pi x)\cos( 2\pi x\frac{2\alpha-1}2)}{2\sin^2(\pi x)}$$

It's not immediate to me why the integral along this contour tends to zero as $N\to\infty$, could you, what am I missing?

@Zima I think you'll need to parameterize each segment, bound the integrand on each one, and then apply the M-L inequality. Each integral should then be $O(n^{-1})$ (or potentially $O(n^{-2})$, though I’m leaning towards $O(n^{-1})$—I haven’t worked through all the details).

@Zima On the contour, at $\alpha\in[0;1]$
$$|\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha z}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2-x^2}|<|\frac{e^{2\pi i\alpha z}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}||\frac1{z^2-x^2}|<|\frac{const}{z^2-x^2}|$$ (we avoid "dangerous points $e^{2\pi iz}-1=0$)

Here is an alternative method for evaluating the sum. I proved here that if $k < x < k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 \pi i \alpha n}}{x + n} & = e^{-x i 2 \pi \{ \alpha \} + x \pi i} \dfrac{\pi}{\sin x \pi}
\end{align*}
where $\{ \alpha \}$ is the fraction function. Using this, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 \pi i \alpha n}}{x^2-n^2} & = \frac{1}{2x} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 \pi i \alpha n}}{x + n} - \frac{1}{2x} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 \pi i \alpha n}}{-x + n}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{2x} e^{-x i 2 \pi \{ \alpha \} + x \pi i} \dfrac{1}{\sin x \pi} + \frac{\pi}{2x} e^{x i 2 \pi \{ \alpha \} - x \pi i} \dfrac{1}{\sin x \pi}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} \dfrac{1}{2\sin x \pi} (e^{-x i 2 \pi \{ \alpha \} + x \pi i} + e^{x i 2 \pi \{ \alpha \} - x \pi i})
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} \dfrac{\cos (x \pi (2 \{ \alpha \} - 1))}{\sin x \pi}
\end{align}

Here, I answer the OP's question directly. While Poisson's summation formula yields the correct result, it does not seem to provide a rigorous derivation.
Poisson's summation formula:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty F(n+t) & = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \tilde{F} (2 \pi m) e^{2 \pi i m t}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\tilde{F} (y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(s) e^{-i y s} ds
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
F (s) = \frac{e^{2 \pi i \alpha s}}{x^2-s^2}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\tilde{F} (y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 \pi i \alpha s - iy s}}{x^2-s^2} ds  \qquad  (1)
\end{align*}
We have the Fourier transform:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i ys}}{x^2-s^2} ds & = \frac{\pi}{x} \sin (xy) sgn (y)
\end{align*}
Using this in (1):
\begin{align*}
\tilde{F} (y) = \frac{\pi}{x} \sin (x (2 \pi \alpha - y)) sgn (2 \pi \alpha - y)
\end{align*}
and putting $y=2 \pi m$:
\begin{align*}
\tilde{F} (2 \pi m) = \frac{\pi}{x} \sin (x 2 \pi (\alpha - m)) sgn (2 \pi (\alpha - m))
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty F(n+t) & =\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \tilde{F} (2 \pi m) e^{2 \pi i m t}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \sin (x 2 \pi (\alpha - m)) sgn (2 \pi (\alpha - m)) e^{2 \pi i m t}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \sin (x 2 \pi (\alpha + m)) sgn (2 \pi (\alpha + m)) e^{-2 \pi i m t}
\end{align*}
Presence of sgn:
Put $\alpha = r + \{ \alpha \}$ where $\{ \alpha \}$ is the fractional part of $\alpha$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty F(n+t) & = \frac{\pi}{x} \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \sin (2 \pi x (r+m + \{ \alpha \})) sgn (2 \pi (r+m + \{ \alpha \})) e^{-2 \pi i m t} 
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} e^{2 \pi i t r} \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \sin (2 \pi x (r+m + \{ \alpha \})) sgn (2 \pi (r+m + \{ \alpha \})) e^{-2 \pi i (m+r) t}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} e^{2 \pi i t r} \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \sin (2 \pi x (m + \{ \alpha \})) sgn (2 \pi (m + \{ \alpha \})) e^{-2 \pi i m t}
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} e^{2 \pi i t r} [- \sum_{m=-\infty}^{-1} \sin (2 \pi x (m + \{ \alpha \})) e^{-2 \pi i m t} + \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sin (2 \pi x (m + \{ \alpha \})) e^{-2 \pi i m t}]
\end{align*}
Summing geometric series and taking imaginary part:
Then $t=0$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 \pi i \alpha n}}{x^2-n^2} & = \frac{\pi}{x} [- \sum_{m=-\infty}^{-1} \sin (2 \pi x (m+\{ \alpha \})) + \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sin (2 \pi x (m + \{ \alpha \}))]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} [\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sin (2 \pi x (m-\{ \alpha \})) + \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sin (2 \pi x (m + \{ \alpha \}))]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} Im [\sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{i2 \pi x (m-\{ \alpha \})} + \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{i2 \pi x (m + \{ \alpha \})})]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} Im [ \frac{e^{-i2 \pi x \{ \alpha \}}}{e^{- i2 \pi x} - 1} + \frac{e^{i2 \pi x \{ \alpha \}}}{1-e^{i2 \pi x}}]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} Im [-\frac{e^{-i2 \pi x \{ \alpha \} +i \pi x}}{e^{i \pi x} - e^{-i \pi x}} - \frac{e^{i2 \pi x \{ \alpha \} - i \pi x}}{e^{i \pi x} - e^{-i \pi x}}]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} Im [\frac{i}{2} \frac{e^{-i2 \pi x \{ \alpha \} +i \pi x}}{\sin (\pi x)} + \frac{i}{2} \frac{e^{i2 \pi x \{ \alpha \} - i \pi x}}{\sin (\pi x)}]
\nonumber \\
& = \frac{\pi}{x} \frac{\cos (\pi x (2\{ \alpha \} - 1))}{\sin (\pi x)}
\end{align*}
giving the correct answer.
How to make it legitimate?
Doing $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{2 \pi i xm} = \frac{1}{1-e^{2 \pi i x}}$ is not legitimate as this
\begin{align*}
(1 - e^{2 \pi i x}) \sum_{n=0}^N e^{2 \pi i xm} = 1 - e^{2\pi i (N+1)x} = 1 - \cos (2 \pi (N+1)x) - i \sin (2 \pi (N+1)x)
\end{align*}
is ill-defined in the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$.
How do you adjust the above calculation to make it legitimate?
