# Riemann hypothesis like conjecture for a non-UFD?

Tags: ring-theory, conjectures, zeta-functions, euler-product

I got inspired by quadratic rings and zeta functions. I know for instance that the norm $a^2 + 17 b^2$ for the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is multiplicative yet the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is not a UFD !!

The norm of that ring is $a^2 + 17 b^2$

I was thinking about this related zeta analogue , the analytic continuation of the Euler product

$$\zeta_{17}(s) = \prod_p (1 + \frac{1}{p^s - 1})$$

where $p$ is an irreducible element of the form $a + b \sqrt{-17}$.

This function $\zeta_{17}$ has a simple pole at $s=1$ and it has no zero's or poles for $s = 1 + t i$ for nonzero real $t$.
(correct me if I am wrong but I think I have proved it)

Now I conjecture that all the zero's of $\zeta_{17}$ are on the real line or have $Re(s) < 0$ or $Re(s) = 1/2$.

Is this true ?

Is this an open problem ?

If open, does this belong to a known generalization of the zeta function ?
Keep in mind this is not the function $f(s) = \sum \frac{1}{(a^2 + 17 b^2)^s}$ nor $g(s) = \sum \frac{1}{(a + \sqrt{-17} b)^s}$ and the related ring is not a UFD.

Again , this is not the same function as [Closed form for $A=\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{0<a^2 + 17 b^2 < k} \frac{1}{a^2 + 17 b^2} - \sum_{k<a^2 + 17 b^2 < k^2} \frac{1}{a^2 + 17 b^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723714/closed-form-for-a-lim-k-to-infty-sum-0a2-17-b2-k-frac1a2)

( although that might interest you. And in fact one can wonder about the regularization of this function at $s=1$ but that is not the question here )

Finally I have to say that I am not clear about how the analytic continuation should actually be done , how far it goes etc.

Using taylor and monodromy theorem works but it is probably not so efficient.
We should get half-planes rather than circles I assume.
I think taking the log of the euler product will help ?

Comment: I think all Riemann Hypothesis type conjectures are related/for euclidean domains, finite fields and ideals with unique factorization (dedekind domain). So this would not be a typical special case. But I am no expert.