# What does the 3rd volume of Lehrbuch der Algebra of Heinrich Weber talk about?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I don't know the German language and I stumbled upon this book. I tried google translate and utterly failed. I just need to know what this volume is mainly about.

Comment: It means "Textbook of Algebra". Why are you trying to read a book whose language you don't understand?

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: I did use precisely that book to write my thesis...:) It speaks of several things, but what I was interested in is algebraic number theory, elliptic functions and very particularly (for me), the j-invariant for elliptic curves. If I remember correctly (and I wouldn't trust this too much), there was a list of its values for several cases. It was a great help back then. I suppose nowadays other more modern books have these lists.

Comment: Here is the link      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A338diqTpYNWZnIvinfUXnrAtufHGT2p/view?usp=sharing     I really need to understand this book because I know a professor working on this book.

Comment: I looked it up. The book is obviously a bit dated in its terminology. It calls polynomial functions *ganze Functionen*. Today we only use that term to refer to complex entire functions. Also, I don't understand why the spelling is Function and not Funktion (with a *k* instead of a *c*).  Regardless, see (https://m.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/articles/pdf/weber.pdf)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the given tags and the given link. The book's name in the given links is elliptic functions and algebraic numbers and NOT textbook of algebra.

Comment: @Fakemistake Yeah you are right. I am confused as well now. See (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438643/translation-of-webers-lehrbuch-der-algebra-vol-1-2-3)

Comment: @Fakemistake The book's name at the link is: "Lehrbuch der Algebra, Dritter Band, Elliptische Funktionen und Algebraische Zahlen". This is perfectly reasonable. What is confusing about it?

Comment: @ParthivBasu Which link do you refer to? The scan from Cornell says "Elliptische Funktionen" with a "k" and not a "c". So everything is OK, it seems.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It was from a version I downloaded from libgen. It read  *Nächster Gegenstand der Betrachtung sind ganze rationale oder ganze Functionen ....* The confusion was that elliptic functions are not exactly something you'll find in a book called textbook of algebra.

Comment: @ParthivBasu Elliptic functions here are in the section algebraic number theory and elliptic curves, which makes sense. That this all belongs to "algebra" is perhaps "confusing". Nowadays it would rather belong to number theory.